# azcopy always creates a folder structure when uploading files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have a local directory what needs to be synced to a specific folder to my Azure Blob Storage.
Unfortunately azcopy always creates a subfolder in the target directory.

local folder:
C:/local/vacation

Uploadfolder:
xxx.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/jpg

I want all JPGs that are within the local folder into the upload folder.
But azcopy always creates the folder "vacation" in my upload folder :(

This is the code:

```
$localFolder = "C:/local/vacation"
$targetFolder= "xxx.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/jpg"  (# here is the actual SAS URI)
azcopy copy $localfolder $targetfolder --include-pattern "*.jpg" --recursive=true
```

Comment: You should try azcopy copy "C:\local\vacation\*" <destination>
That should achieve what they're trying to do with that operation-- It'll just strip the parent directory from the destination

Comment: Ok, I tried it. Unfortunately it still creates the folder. I hoped that it directly uploads all the images flat into the destionation folder. But it always creates the folder name of the origin :( Any other idea @sumanthMarigodwa-MFST

Comment: I also tried "C:\local\vacation\*" and "C:\local\vacation\"
Didnt work either :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***Sync operation*** to perform the copy without the directory being created.

```
azcopy sync "C:\local\vacation" "https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/jpg/?SAStoken" --include-pattern "*.jpg" --recursive=true
```

**Example:**

For the first command as you can see below I ran to sync the jpg files to the destination for the first time , then I added another jpg file in my local machine folder and ran the command for second time it synced the 1 new file to the destination.

[image]

[image]

The Above highlighted files are present on my local machine directory and when I performed sync they were only copied from local machine to azure and the directory was not created as subfolder.

**Reference:**

[Synchronize with Azure Blob storage by using AzCopy v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-synchronize?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)

Comment: Azure Pipelines don't have a sync option.

Comment: Hello @ErikPhilips,yes you are correct but the ask is not for azure pipelines.

Comment: Correct, that's why I made a comment and still upvoted.

Comment: I think this is not working. Here again the problem. I have a folder that looks like this C:\photos\2021 and C:\photos\2021 . Within those folders i have some sub folders with images (JPG). I want to upload ALL JPGs to a destination folder in cloud without all the subfolders. So the new structure is like  xxx.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/jpg/image1.jpg and so on. But azcopy sync always copies also the folder structure :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one of the following:

```
$localFolder = "C:/local/vacation/**"
$targetFolder= "xxx.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/jpg"  
azcopy copy $localfolder $targetfolder --include-pattern "*.jpg" --recursive=true
```

or

```
$localFolder = "C:/local/vacation/**/*.jpg"
$targetFolder= "xxx.blob.core.windows.net/files/images/jpg" 
azcopy copy $localfolder $targetfolder --recursive=true
```

Comment: I receive in both cases: Cannot perform sync due to error: sync must happen between source and destination of the same type, e.g. either file
 <-> file, or directory/container <-> directory/container

Answer (score 0):

After trying plenty of stuff. It seems that within the azcopy sync it is not possible.
Only with azcopy copy this works. What a pitty :/

Answer (score -1):

```bash
azcopy copy './*' 'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/path/to/dir' --recursive
```